# What is the difference between Holdout dataset vs Validation dataset?

Tags: machine-learning

What is the difference between the Holdout dataset and the Validation dataset in Machine Learning context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Validation dataset is used during training to track the performance of your model on "unseen" data. I wrote the unseen in quotes because although the model doesn't directly see the data in validation set, you will optimize the hyper-parameters to decrease the loss on validation set (since increasing val loss will mean over-fitting). However, by doing so, you may over-fit the hyper-parameters to validation set (So that the loss will be low on that specific validation set, but will become worse on any other unseen set). That's why you usually keep another 3rd set, called **test set** (or held-out set), which will be your truly unseen data, and you will test the performance of your model on that test set only once, after training your final model.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir/ma'am! An article on Wikipedia got confused as they've mentioned Holdout set and Test set as two different things. I am new to ML and really appreciate your help :)

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept the answer if it helped you.